# Simple-LInked Error

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have placed the simple linkedin class on my server and added my api keys etc, however when i call the demo page i get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/mycv/public_html/dev/linkedin_3.2.0.class.php on line 259

this is the code for the area around line: 259

```
  if(is_array($http_code_required)) {
      array_walk($http_code_required, function($value, $key) {
    if(!is_int($value)) {
            throw new LinkedInException('LinkedIn->checkResponse():   $http_code_required must be an integer or an array of integer values');
        }
```

line 259:  seems to refer to the second line starting with array walk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous functions [only became available in PHP 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Line 259 above uses an anonymous function, so that would explain the error if your version pre-dates support.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the anonymous function as a named function and call it in the `checkResponse` function:

```
function **innerfunction**($value, $key) {
    if(!is_int($value)) {
        throw new LinkedInException('LinkedIn->checkResponse(): $http_code_required must be an integer or an array of integer values');
    }
}

private function checkResponse($http_code_required, $response) {
    // check passed data
    if(is_array($http_code_required)) {
        array_walk($http_code_required, **innerfunction**($value, $key));
    }
}
```